# Problem to Load HubSpot Forms in LWC Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import hubSpotFile from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/HubSpotV2';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class FormsScriptHubspot extends LightningElement {
  @track scriptLoaded = false;

  connectedCallback() {
    // Load script from Static Resources
    loadScript(this, hubSpotFile)
      .then(() => {
        this.scriptLoaded = true;
        console.log('Script loaded succesfully');

        // Injetar script HubSpot no HTML
        const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.src = hubSpotFile;
        scriptElement.onload = () => {
          const formId = 'HASH_HERE';
          const form = hbspt.forms.create({
            region: 'REGION_HERE',
            portalId: 'ID_HERE',
            formId: formId,
          });

          const divMain = this.template.querySelector('.slds-m-around_medium');
          form.render(divMain);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Problem to Load Script:', error);
      });
  }
}
```

I've created a Static Resource with HubSpot JS Script main link (https://js.hsforms.net/forms/embed/v2.js) theres a function inside the Script, that render a Div with iframe that contains the forms.

[image: Localhost]

At Salesforce:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forms')
at eval (formsScriptHubspot.js:1:762)